# Can anyone explain why am i getting "expression must have pointer to object type" in the following code:

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<array>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    system("cls");
    int n, l, m;
    int a[100][100], b[100][100], m[100][100];
    //inputing
    cout<<"For the multiplication of the matrices NxL & LxM: \n";
    cout<<"Enter N: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter L: ";
    cin>>l;
    cout<<"Enter M: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"Enter the first matrix: ";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
            cout<<i<<":";
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"         \n";
    }
    cout<<"Enter the second matrix: ";
    for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            cout<<i<<":";
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"         \n";
    }
    //multiplying
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
            m[i][j] = a[i][j]*b[j][i]);
        }
    }
    getch();
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

> I am trying to multiply two matrices in this code, but this statement is creating a major problem. Please tell how to solve this error.
> it is giving me error in the line `m[i][j] = a[i][j]*b[j][i]);`

Comment: One possible reason is that you have an `int` called `m` and an `int[100][100]` called `m`. Give your variables meaningful names, not just single characters.

Comment: First of all, why you have declared 'm' as an array of int as well as an int type variable?

Comment: you need to look at the first error first. The problem is in line 9 already: https://godbolt.org/z/PGhjrx. When posting a question, please include the complete error message, not only part of it

Comment: @Aayush, slightly off the track remark -- get a better development environment. Looks like you are using old DOS-C env. Best would be start looking at linux / gcc env.

Answer (score 1):

Your code previously had few minor bugs, like missing `}`. Here I have corrected it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    system("cls");
    int n, l, m;
    int a[100][100], b[100][100], ar[100][100];
    //inputing
    cout<<"For the multiplication of the matrices NxL & LxM: \n";
    cout<<"Enter N: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter L: ";
    cin>>l;
    cout<<"Enter M: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"Enter the first matrix: ";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
            cout<<i<<":";
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"         \n";
    }
    cout<<"Enter the second matrix: ";
    for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            cout<<i<<":";
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"         \n";
    }
    //multiplying
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
            ar[i][j] = a[i][j]*b[j][i];
        }
    }
    getch();
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

Things I have changed:-

1. Added `{` at line no 35
2. Changed the name of the third array. Where the result is to be stored. Actually, there was an ambiguity due to the name of the variable and the 2-d array being the same.

Comment: I got the answer after writing this code. But still thank you very much brother!

Comment: @Aayush Gupta Welcome